# Python Pandas Dataframe with Dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I am a beginner and currently try to create the following data structure/table with pandas:

table with 3 columns

| Date of sale | Date of shipment | Date of delivery |
| --- | --- | --- |

1. First I want to create in column 1 (Date of sale) random dates. For example 50 dates from 2022
2. Second, I want to produce the same amount of dates ​​in column 2 (Date of shipment). However, these should dependent on the values ​​in column 1 by adding a certain number of days in each case.
   For example: random date on column 1 is 01.01.2023, then date on column 2 should be +5 days, so 06.01.2023.
3. Third, the same should happen on column 3, but with the difference, that this depends on column 2.

Last example:
random generated date in column 1 is 01.01.2023
random number of dates (+3) added to this date and generate new date for column 2: 04.01.2023
random number of dates (+2) added to new date and generate new date for column 3: 06.01.2023

we get a data structure with following content:

| Date of sale | Date of shipment | Date of delivery |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2023 | 04.01.2023 | 06.01.2023 |

Thank you so much!

Best

i try to create a table in python pandas with 3 columns. First column should contain random dates. Second column should contain dates depending on column 1 +x days. Same for column 3 but depending on column 2.

Answer (score 0):

Example that demonstrates how you can achieve this

```py
import random
from datetime import timedelta

import pandas as pd

# Set the number of dates and the starting year
num_dates = 50
start_year = 2022

# Generate random dates for column 1
dates_column1 = pd.date_range(start=f"1/1/{start_year}", periods=num_dates)


# Function to add a specific number of days to a given date
def add_days(date, num_days):
    return date + timedelta(days=num_days)


# Generate dates for column 2 based on column 1
dates_column2 = [add_days(date, random.randint(1, 10)) for date in dates_column1]

# Generate dates for column 3 based on column 2
dates_column3 = [add_days(date, random.randint(1, 10)) for date in dates_column2]

# Create a DataFrame with the three columns
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date of sale": dates_column1,
                   "Date of shipment": dates_column2,
                   "Date of delivery": dates_column3})

# Convert the dates to the desired format
df["Date of sale"] = df["Date of sale"].dt.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
df["Date of shipment"] = df["Date of shipment"].dt.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
df["Date of delivery"] = df["Date of delivery"].dt.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")

# Print the resulting DataFrame
print(df)
#    Date of sale Date of shipment Date of delivery
# 0    01.01.2022       04.01.2022       06.01.2022
# 1    02.01.2022       09.01.2022       13.01.2022
# 2    03.01.2022       11.01.2022       15.01.2022
# 3    04.01.2022       10.01.2022       12.01.2022
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html)

```
num = 10  # 50
origin = pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01')

days1 = pd.to_timedelta(np.random.randint(0, 366, num), unit='D')
days2 = days1 + pd.to_timedelta(np.random.randint(1, 10, num), unit='D')
days3 = days2 + pd.to_timedelta(np.random.randint(1, 10, num), unit='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sales': origin + days1,
                   'Shipment': origin + days2,
                   'Delivery': origin + days3})
```

Output:

```
>>> df
       Sales   Shipment   Delivery
0 2023-08-12 2023-08-18 2023-08-22
1 2023-07-09 2023-07-14 2023-07-20
2 2023-07-07 2023-07-10 2023-07-19
3 2023-11-26 2023-12-02 2023-12-08
4 2023-11-17 2023-11-22 2023-11-29
5 2023-12-01 2023-12-05 2023-12-14
6 2023-07-09 2023-07-12 2023-07-16
7 2023-10-07 2023-10-16 2023-10-20
8 2023-02-28 2023-03-05 2023-03-14
9 2023-10-22 2023-10-23 2023-11-01
```